# compare line to string variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have txt file with date value, line by line

[image]

I try to compare them to today date in powershell but its not working

```
$DateTimeNow = (Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')
$data2 = get-content "output.txt"
$z= @()
foreach($line2 in $data2)
{

  if($line2 -match $DateTimeNow){
       write-host "same date"
    }

}
```

the compare with `"match"` not work, I have try `-eq` and `=` but nothing better.
Have you any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: please, DO NOT post images of code/error-text/sample-data. why? lookee ... >>> Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input dates all use 2-digit notation for the year (`20` for `2020`), but your string representing today's date uses 4-digits. Change to the appropriate format and it will work:

```
$DateTimeNow = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yy'
```

Comment: @guillaumezac it took me a few takes to spot it too ^_^